# how to call second function after first is executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling two function on change event.

```
function1();
function2();
```

`function1()` : is a ajax call
`function2()` : is getting executed before function1().

Why is this happening?

Any help?

Comment: the function 1 has to accept a callback method, inside which you will call function2... the callback will be executed after the ajax call is finished

Comment: you can get a basic idea from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: You've to learn more about two concepts 1) Ajax calls and how they're asynchronous. 2) Javascript callbacks. Read on these two and you'll know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please look at the code written below:

function1() {
  $.ajax({
  url: myurl,
  type: 'GET',
  async:false,
  success: function(response) {
     function2();
  }
 });
}
```

Please note here the "async:false" will ensure that the success method will call when the first function has been successfully executed. So you should use "async:false" to ensure that the function2() will call after function1().

Answer (score 3):

The first A of `Ajax` means `asynchronous`, i.e. the regular Javascript program flow will continue while the Ajax request is still being processed. Therefore, `function2` will be executed before the Ajax request initiated from `function1` will be finished.

Solution: Every asynchronous method in Javascript will provide you with a so-called `callback`, which is a function that will be called after the asynchronous method finished. In `jQuery.ajax()` this callback is provided with the parameter `success`. If you put the call to `function2` inside this callback, it will work.

```
function1() {
   ...
   $.ajax({
      url: '...',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
         // this will be executed after the asynchronous method finishes
         function2();
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if `function1()` is ajax function then call `function2()` on the success of your ajax

if you are using jquery ajax

```
function1() {
   $.ajax({
      url: myurl,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(response) {
         function2();
      }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your function2 after successful  response from Ajax.

```
function function1()
{
  //Ajax Call
  ..
  ..

  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    function2();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally Call like this

```
function1(function() { 

           function2(); 

        });
```

If it is Ajax call like this

```
function function1() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "url",
        type: 'POST',
    }).success(function (html) {
        function2();
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r49C6/1/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery ajax returns deferred object (http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), its really usefull for things like yours. By the way, deferred object support chaining pattern, so you can call more than one function.

So, to run one function after another you can do next

```
function ajaxCall(){
   return $.get('your/api/call', {param:1});
}

function fun1(){
   console.log('Function 1 was called');
}

function fun2(){
   console.log('Function 2 was called');
}


ajaxCall().done(fun1).done(fun2);
```

Or you can use $.when

```
$.when( $.get('your/api/call') )
   .then(function(){ alert(1); })
   .then(function(){ alert(2); });
```

Usefull links:

[jQuery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

[jQuery when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

[jQuery deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)